# Android 4.3 Native crash in unknown.unknown

Tags: android

I received bug report which happened to mostly Android 4.3. Is there any help to fix this crash?

Following are on tracks from Google Dev Console

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/t03gxx/t03g:4.3/JSS15J/N7100XXUEML3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 27052, tid: 27076, name: AsyncTask #2 >>> com.mypackage <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 6b453000
r0 6b453000 r1 4272a58c r2 00000457 r3 d7307250
r4 e06c8384 r5 44bb8b21 r6 31156588 r7 16d07a4a
r8 980282c1 r9 10dc20f1 sl a201840f fp 36720440
ip 4272a5c0 sp 618257e0 lr 40b767a7 pc 401e5094 cpsr 20000010
d0 000000003f800000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 3f80000000000000
d4 3faaaaab3f800000 d5 0000000000000000
d6 bf80000000000000 d7 3f8000003f800000
d8 000000003f800000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000001 d17 4040000000000000
d18 3dea39ef35793c76 d19 0065004e005f0061
d20 3f8948b0fcd6e9e0 d21 3ff0000000000000
d22 3fd24998d6307188 d23 3fcc7288e957b53b
d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
d26 3fe62e42fefa39ef d27 4000000000000000
d28 40008df2d49d41f1 d29 3fb0f4a31edab38b
d30 4059000000000000 d31 4024000000000000
scr 60000090

backtrace:
#00 pc 0001d094 /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+176)
#01 pc 0004b7a3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#02 pc 0007fa91 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#03 pc 0007fb8b /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#04 pc 0011a238 /system/lib/libskia.so
#05 pc 0011a654 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkWEBPImageDecoder::onDecode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+256)
#06 pc 001146c8 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkImageDecoder::decode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkBitmap::Config, SkImageDecoder::Mode, bool)+168)
#07 pc 0007d7d5 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#08 pc 0007de8f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#09 pc 0001e44c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#10 pc 0004e913 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#11 pc 00027860 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 0002bdf8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#13 pc 00060a89 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
#14 pc 00060ab3 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#15 pc 00055823 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#16 pc 0000cb58 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#17 pc 0000ccd4 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)

code around pc:
401e5074 e2522020 3a000008 e3c1c01f e28cc040
401e5084 e8b10ff0 f5dcf040 e2522020 849c3020
401e5094 e8a00ff0 2afffff9 e2822020 e312001f
401e50a4 0a00000c e1b0ce02 28b100f0 48b10300
401e50b4 28a000f0 48a00300 e1b0cf02 24913004
401e50c4 40d140b2 24803004 40c040b2 e3120001
401e50d4 15d13000 15c03000 e8bd0fe0 e8bd4011
401e50e4 e12fff1e e3520004 3a00007b e88d0fe0
401e50f4 e2605000 e2055003 e1a0c185 e26ce020
401e5104 e4913004 e2422004 e1b05f85 44c03001
401e5114 41a03423 24c03001 21a03423 24c03001
401e5124 21a03423 e3520004 3a000064 e310001c
401e5134 0a000007 e4915004 e2422004 e1834e15
401e5144 e1a03c35 e4804004 e3520004 2afffff6
401e5154 3a00005a e2522020 3a00004d e35c0018
401e5164 0a000033 e35c0008 0a000018 e491c004

code around lr:
40b76784 429a1962 4b09dd06 462a4621 f7fe447b
40b76794 e006f9cb 0110f100 9808462a f7d21909
40b767a4 a801e946 fa90f7fe bf00bdfe 0004e573
40b767b4 4607b5f7 a801460e 46144639 f7fe461d
40b767c4 9801fa5b f7ff4631 2c00fa73 2d00db05
40b767d4 6883db03 429a1962 4b09dd06 462a4621
40b767e4 f7fe447b e006f9a1 0110f100 9808462a
40b767f4 f7d21909 a801e91c fa66f7fe bf00bdfe
40b76804 0004e51f 46022b01 460cb513 4611d00c
40b76814 f7fea801 4621fa31 f7ff9801 f7fefa49
40b76824 a801f9a5 fa50f7fe 2b01bd1c b5134602
40b76834 d00c460c a8014611 fa1ef7fe 98014621
40b76844 fa36f7ff f992f7fe f7fea801 bd1cfa3d
40b76854 46022b01 460cb513 4611d00c f7fea801
40b76864 4621fa0b f7ff9801 f7fefa23 a801f97f
40b76874 fa2af7fe 2b01bd1c b5134602 d00c460c
```